# Why is apply not behaving as expected with custom javascript object function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to grasp how the apply and call methods work but the result of the below code has confused me completely.

```
var arr = new Array(100);
console.log.apply(console, arr);
```

This results in console.log() being called 100 times ( and outputs undefined as arr is 100 in size and has no values in it)

so why can I not produce similar with the following

```
var obj = {
     i:0

    };
    obj.x = function(){
     console.log("count: "+this.i);
     this.i++;
    }

    var arr = new Array(100);
    obj.x.apply(obj, arr);
```

what I am expecting is to print out "count: 0"...al the way to "count: 99", instead it just fires once producing "count: 0" as the only output. clearly I am not understanding and would appreciate any clarification

Comment: *"This results in console.log() being called 100 times"* no, it calls console.log once, with 100 arguments. your second snippet calls `obj.x` once, with 100 arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `apply` does is take an array of arguments, and call the function in question using those arguments.

So for example:

```
function foo(a,b) {
    alert(a+b);
}
foo.apply(null, [1,2]); // alerts 3
```

Does that make sense?

In general, when in doubt, consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: yes I understand that but if I pass an empty array to apply on the console.log it it still calls the console.log 100 times but why would it not do this for my function?

Comment: `console.log` takes an arbitrary number of arguments and logs each one in turn. In some browsers, that's 100 individual logs. On others, they're logged one after the other inline. The observed behaviour of one function (`console.log`) isn't nearly enough to determine what the behaviour of a totally unrelated function (`Function.apply`)

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpreted the first snippet.

> This results in console.log() being called 100 times

No, it calls `console.log` once with 100 arguments. your second snippet calls `obj.x` once, with 100 arguments.

To make the second snippet perform the same way, you have to iterate over the arguments.

```
var obj = {
    i:0
};
obj.x = function(){
    for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
        console.log("count: "+this.i);
        this.i++;
    }
}

var arr = new Array(100);
obj.x.apply(obj, arr); // 0-99
obj.x("foo","bar","foobar"); // 100-102
```